# HTML reset button not working properly

Tags: php, html, forms, http-post

I have a basic sum example with some `PHP` and `HTML`, inside this `PHP` page the reset button only resetting  first two input field, and it is not resetting the third answer field. I dont know what is the error with this cause i am new to `PHP`. someone please help me to fix this.

**code**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Title goes here</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="" method="post">
<label>Enter Num1:</label>
<input type="text" name="num1" id="num1" /><br>
<label>Enter Num2:</label>
<input type="text" name="num2" id="num2" /><br><br>

<input type="radio" name="rad" value="add"/>addition
<input type="radio" name="rad" value="sub"/>sub

<input  type="submit" name="btn_submit" value="fire">

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['btn_submit']))
    {
        $num1 = $_POST['num1'];
        $num2 = $_POST['num2'];
        $rad_val = $_POST['rad'];
        if($rad_val=="add"){
        $total =  $num1+$num2;      
        }
        else if($rad_val=="sub"){
        $total =  $num1-$num2;
        }     
        echo "<SCRIPT TYPE=\"text/javascript\">

document.getElementById(\"num1\").value= $num1;
document.getElementById(\"num2\").value= $num2;
</SCRIPT>";
        echo "<label>Answer is:</label> <input type=\"text\" name=\"rad\" value = $total />";
        echo"<input  type=\"reset\" name=\"reset\" value=\"reset\" />";

    }
    else if(isset($_POST['reset'])){
    echo "<script>window.location = 'your_page.php';</script>";
    }
?>


</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand the `type=reset` [Example how it works](http://jsfiddle.net/zGayA/) It is not a post, but it resets the input values. If you want to refresh the page, why don't just `<a href="your_page.php">Reset</a>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reset function loads the your_page.php. So the initial value on that page might be needed to be changed to 0. Could you give an example of your_page.php?

You can trigger a page refresh by changing the line

```
echo"<input  type=\"reset\" name=\"reset\" value=\"reset\" />";
```

to

```
echo"<input  type=\"reset\" name=\"reset\" value=\"reset\" onclick= \"window.location = 'your_page.php';\"/>";
```

**OR**

Even better. Just Reset the value in the Answer to 0, This will save on the page reload.

Add an ID to the result field :

```
<input type=\"text\" name=\"rad\" id=\"rad\" value = $total />";
```

And change te value on the reset click/

```
echo"<input  type=\"reset\" name=\"reset\" value=\"reset\" onclick= \" document.getElementById(\"rad\").value= 0;\"/>";
```

Comment: its the current page i used that line to reload the same page put it is not checking the `else if(isset($_POST['reset']))` condition

Comment: Okay firstly. When you are doing a redirect as in  

echo "<script>window.location = 'your_page.php';</script>";

The form is not posted. Thus the page is just reloaded. The isset($_POST['reset']) will thus never be true. 

I will update my answer to show correct use of Reset button.

Answer (score 1):

With Jquery you can reset to any value but you net to prevent the default action:

Example:

```
$('#Reset').click(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#element').val('default');
    $('#element2').val('default');
    $('#element3').val('default');      
});
```